# Definition of cognitive load

Tags: cognitive-psychology, memory, terminology, definition

Wikipedia's page on [cognitive load](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_load) starts with

> In cognitive psychology, cognitive load refers to the effort being used in the working memory. Cognitive load theory differentiates cognitive load into three types: intrinsic, extraneous, and germane. [...]

The page does not seem well written because it quickly gets to odd specifics like:

> High cognitive load in the elderly has been shown to affect their center of balance.[[5]](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0361-9230(02)00770-0)

Is that first quote a good definition or is too narrow? Is cognitive load really all about working memory?

Comment: +1 This might be a nice question for @StevenJeuris I think